# Prove there are infinitely many squares which are the sum of two tetrahedral numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $T_n = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(n+2)$ denote the $n$th Tetrahedral number. The first several solutions to squares as sums of two Tetrahedral numbers are {T_n,T_m,a^2}
1 5 6\
1 8 11\
1 22 45\
1 24 51\
1 63 209\
2 9 13\
2 23 48\
2 94 378\
2 96 390\
8 12 22\
8 17 33\
8 38 100\
8 111 484\
9 12 23\
9 21 44\
9 28 65\
10 15 30\
10 169 905\
13 83 315\
15 22 52\
15 33 85\
15 42 118\
15 87 338\
16 30 76\
16 82 310\
17 30 77\
22 24 68\
22 28 78\
23 24 70\
23 41 121\
23 132 628\
30 34 110\
31 78 296\
33 86 341\
38 81 319\
41 68 259\
41 85 344\
42 50 188\
48 71 286\
54 65 275\
56 134 664\
58 167 908\
62 128 632\
64 81 371\
65 79 365\
65 152 803\
68 78 370\
78 96 484\
78 112 568\
79 138 730\
79 161 891\
82 159 882\
96 145 819\
129 144 935\
Prove that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If you admit a negative number $(m,n)$,we can show there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: For what it's worth, 1, 6, 11, 45, 51, 209, 660099 are "Numbers $n$ such that $n^2 - 1$ is a tetrahedral number, see https://oeis.org/A216269

Comment: There are two parametric solutions of $v^2=1/6n(n+1)(n+2)+1/6m(m+1)(m+2).$ $k$ is arbitrary integer.
$(m,n,v)=( (6k+1)(2k+1), 6k^2+4k-1, (3k+1)(6k^2+4k+1) ),( (6k+5)(2k+1), 6k^2+8k+1, (3k+2)(6k^2+8k+3) ).$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are infinitely many integer solutions of equation $(1).$

$$y^2=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}+\frac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{6}\tag{1}$$
Substitute $n = s - m$ to equation $(1)$ then we get
$$6y^2 = (3s+6)m^2+(-3s^2-6s)m+s^3+2s+3s^2$$

Let $s = 2t$ and $x = m - t$ then we get

$$3y^2 = (3t+3)x^2+t(t+2)(t+1)$$

Let $t = u^2-1$ then we get

$$y^2-u^2x^2 = \frac{(u^2-1)(u^2+1)u^2}{3}$$

Hence we get $(x,y)= \left(\Large{\frac{u^2+2}{3},\frac{2u^3+u}{3}}\right)$

To make $x$ and $y$ integers, let $u = 3k + 1$ then we get a parametric solution of euation $(1).$

$(m,n,y)=(\ (6k+1)(2k+1),\ 6k^2+4k-1,\ (3k+1)(6k^2+4k+1) \,)$
$k$ is arbitrary integer.

Similarly, $u = 3k + 2$ then we get another solution.

$(m,n,y)=(\ (2k+1)(6k+5),\ 6k^2+8k+1,\ (3k+2)(6k^2+8k+3) \,)$

Numerical example with $k\leqq 10.$

$(m,n,y)=(21, 9, 44),(65, 31, 231),(133, 65, 670),(225, 111, 1469),(341, 169, 2736),(481, 239, 4579),(645, 321, 7106),(833, 415, 10425),(1045, 521, 14644),(1281, 639, 19871),$
$(5, 1, 6), (33, 15, 85), (85, 41, 344), (161, 79, 891), (261, 129, 1834), (385, 191, 3281), (533, 265, 5340), (705, 351, 8119), (901, 449, 11726), (1121, 559, 16269), (1365, 681, 21856)$